# Render multiple heights in an isometric tile based map

Tags: java, render, isometric

Good evening everyone.

I've been messing a bit with isometric tile worlds and I have a few doubts about rendering the elements on it.
When I build a single height map I render it first and then add the diferent elements on top, and the displacement of the last seem right.

```
public void render(Graphics2D g2d) {
    for(int i = 0; i < tileGrid.length; i++) {
        Point isop = NeoMath.getInstance().cartToIso(i % yAmmount, i / yAmmount, GlobalDataStorage.tileWidth, GlobalDataStorage.tileHeight);
        TileManager.getInstance().getTileByID(tileGrid[i]).render(g2d, isop.x, isop.y);
    }

    for(Entity entity : entityList) {
        entity.render(g2d);
    }
}
```

(The position of the entity is calculated inside it's update).

With this I have no problems as everything is rendered on the same height, the problem comes when I try to add other floors to it.
Let's say that I want it to have three heights. I have a list of list of tiles instead of the single array, and render every element on them:

```
    public void render(Graphics2D g2d) {
        int flag = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < tileGrid.size(); i++) {
            Point isop = NeoMath.getInstance().cartToIso(i % yAmmount, i / yAmmount, GlobalDataStorage.tileWidth, GlobalDataStorage.tileHeight);
            for(int k = 0; k < tileGrid.get(i).size(); k++) {
    TileManager.getInstance().getTileByID(tileGrid.get(i).get(k)).render(g2d, isop.x, isop.y - (GlobalDataStorage.tileZ * k));
            }
        while(flag < currentList.size() && 
          currentList.get(flag).getPosition().equals(new Point(i % yAmmount, i / 
          yAmmount))) {
            currentList.get(flag).render(g2d);
            flag++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Where the currentList is the list of entities.

With this I have the problem that, when the entities move to a new position, they get overlaped by the tiles, as these are rendered after the entity, and the position of the entity does not change until it reached the destiny. I could change the position to the new one before rendering, but that implies that in the other axis the previous tile get rendered after the entity, making it disapear for a second due to the overlap.

This also mess when I try to draw selection rectangle as it get stuck behind the tiles being rendered. I don't want them to overlap the whole map so can't draw them after all the rendering has been done either.

Does someone know of another approach that I can try out?

Thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw your entire floor layer in a first pass. Then in the second pass draw all walls and objects and moving entities.

> I could change the position to the new one before rendering,

David Brevik, programmer on Diablo, mentions using this option in his GDC talk Diablo: A Classic Games Postmortem. It was his first "What Went Wrong" example!

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VscdPA6sUkc&t=20m17s

Turns out this is a classic hurdle in isometric games.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and thank you for the link to the video, I found it interesting and gave me a new approach about the order in which I render the floor tiles. Thank you for taking your time to reply me ^-^